# How can I use that regex in angularJs expression?

Tags: angularjs, regex

Here I have a string with spaces, and I would like to replace the space(s) to a single dash '-'.

```
var card = "A World Elite Warrior";

console.log("card = " + card.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'-'));
```

The output is a-world-elite-warrior, but I just want to use it in the html template as a angularjs expression like this:

```
<img ng-src="images/cards/{{card.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'-')}}.png"
```

And it can not work, the error message is:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '/' not a primary
>   expression at column 61 of the expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS doesn't support regex in the view. To get around this you can write a simple filter to apply your regex replacement. Here's an example of how you might do this in your case.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.card = "A World Elite Warrior";
    console.log("card = " + $scope.card.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-'));
  })
  .filter('dashes', function() {
    return function(input) {
      input = input || '';
      return input.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{ card | dashes }}
</div>
```

Comment: I did just like you suggested. it works well, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to create a $scope function that carries out the regular expression.  You would then just call the function from your view:

```
$scope.cardChange = function() {
    return $scope.card.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'-');
};
```

```
<img ng-src="images/cards/{{cardChange()}}.png"
```